# How to replace value of string variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need a way to switch between two modes when a button is pressed.

The analogy of my problem:

A button is pushed "on and off" and an alert says "On" or "Off"

How do I get string to alternate between the values: "On" and "Off" by updating the value of string every time I push the button which checks current value and replaces?

**interface**

```
<button onclick="changeState();">Push me</button>
```

**script**

```
<script> 

var string = "up"; 

function changeState(){

  if(string=="up"){
  // switching to off
    var string = "down"; // I'm just redeclaring or declaring a new variable right? scope? 
    alert(Off);
    }else{
    // switching to on assuming current state is off
      var string = "up";
      // new state
      alert('on');
    }

  }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are. I remove 'var' let it global, also remove a `}` spare:

```js
var string = "up";

function changeState() {
  if (string == "up") {
    // switching to off
    string = "down"; // I'm just redeclaring or declaring a new variable right? scope? 
    alert("off");
  } else {
    // switching to on assuming current state is off
    string = "up";
    // new state
    alert('on');
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeState()">Push me</button>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Well this clearly works, not sure what is wrong on my end. Thank you.

Comment: Weird for my end it had to say "else if" for the second condition.

Comment: It's ok, but it's not necessary. If you have another state, such as up, down, disconnected, then use else if, or switch case statement.

Comment: by "push" and "analogy" I meant literally a button, that person would push with their finger or a switch like a light switch.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var string = "up";

function changeState() {
  
  string = string =="up" ? "down" : "up";  

}
```

Comment: terniary variable or something like that, a person showed this to me the other day. Thanks for your answer.